# Entity Framework Update without reading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there a way to update a single table / entity without having to read the entity first into a list.
This is the sql I am trying to achieve.

**Update table set col1 = Case col2 When 0 then 1 else 0 end**
this updates roughly 500,000 records under a second

I do not want to do

```
 List<table> updRecs = Context.tables.toList();
 for each
 {
  if(col1 == 0)
  col2 = true 
  else
  col2 = false
 }
```

Context.SaveChanges();

above is very slow roughly 4 minutes.

Comment: Can you give us more information about your use case? You *can* run raw SQL or a Stored Procedure, but this sounds like an odd situation

Comment: Sounds like a situation where you might want to look into [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended).

Comment: disable changetracking before the loop and activate it afterwards (ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EntityFramework.Extended**

[nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended/)

[git](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended)

```cs
context.Tasks
    .Where(t => t.StatusId == 1)
    .Update(t => new Task { StatusId = 2 });
```

Comment: Useful intro link: http://www.seguetech.com/blog/2015/01/26/performing-bulk-updates-entity-framework-6.1%2B

Comment: is there a limit to how many items can be in the Update. It seems like it can only handle 12965 records at a time, anything more it throws invalid column id error message.